# ASP.NET Core: SignOutAsync() and SignInAsync() in 1 request not possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In my web application I want to make it is possible for logged in user to switch to another user in one click. Easiest way of think is to first signout and immediately signin after with new credentials. But I can't get it to work.

I got my signin-method from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Now I want to do:

```
await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await context.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    authProperties);
```

After SignOutAsync, the claims are still there and the User is still 'IsAuthenticated'. And the SignInAsync will not change anything.

I think it has something to do with the async calls, but I don't know what. Anyone any idea?

Comment: Can you dispose context after sign-out?

Comment: Don't know how?

Comment: Where do you check that *the User is still 'IsAuthenticated'*? If it's in the same request, the changes won't be active. You'd need to redirect the user first in order to pick up the new principal.

Comment: Found out that it's indeed impossible without redirects. So in my OnPost() method I sign out and redirect to another OnGet() method to sign in with the new account. In between I store my data as TempData

Comment: I see a related limitation that `SignInAsync` only takes effect on the next request. But you might not need to sign out, just sign in with the new claims and it should overwrite anything old. I'm doing that to switch users.